# How to move a HBase table from HDFS storage to BLOB storage (and how to check the storage)

Tags: hbase, azure-storage, ambari

So, we have created a table in HBase, in an Azure Cluster but not sure about the storage. How to check if the table is located in blob or not?

I've been searching in the documentation and in the HBase section on the Ambari web.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The storage account that you provided during cluster creation is used for storage. This is typically blob storage. In the HDP Ambari UI under HDFS , you can look for storage account in the config . You can look for this config key called:**fs.defaultFS**

The root directory of data in this FS can be obtained from the HBASE config

Comment: Thanks!! but, what about tables previously created in HDFS?

Comment: Did not quite get that sorrry , if there were already tables there  and this was the wasb storage used , those tables should show up